# Python: How to replace every space in a dictionary to an underscore?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, anki

Im still a beginner so maybe the answer is very easy, but I could not find a solution (at least one I could understand) online.
Currently I am learning famous works of art through the app "Anki". So I imported a deck for it online containing over 700 pieces.

Sadly the names of the pieces are in english and I would like to learn them in my mother language (german). So I wanted to write a script to automate the process of translating all the names inside the app. I started out by creating a dictionary with every artist and their art pieces (to fill this dictionary automatically reading the app is a task for another time).

```
art_dictionary = {
    "Wassily Kandinsky": "Composition VIII",
    "Zhou Fang": "Ladies Wearing Flowers in Their Hair",
 }
```

My plan is to access wikipedia (or any other database for artworks) that stores the german name of the painting (because translating it with a eng-ger dictionary often returns wrong results since the german translation can vary drastically):

1. **replacing every space character inside the name to an underscore**
2. letting python access the wikipedia page of said painting:

   ```
   import re
   from urllib.request import urlopen
   painting_name = "Composition_VIII" #this is manual input of course

   url = "wikipedia.org/wiki/" + painting_name
   page = urlopen(url)
   ```
3. somehow access the german version of the site and extracting the german name of the painting.

   ```
   html = page.read().decode("utf-8")

   pattern = "<title.*?>.*?</title.*?>" #I think Wikipedia stores the title like <i>Title</i>
   match_results = re.search(pattern, html, re.IGNORECASE)
   title = match_results.group()
   title = re.sub("<.*?>", "", title)
   ```
4. storing it in a list or variable
5. inserting it in the anki app

maybe this is impossible or "over-engineering", but I'm learning a lot along the way.

I tried to search for a solution online, but could not find anything similar to my problem.

Comment: As far as I know you can't modify a key in a dictionary, but you can add a new key:value pair based on the old one, then delete the old key.

Comment: Please indicate whether you want to change " " to "_" only in the values or in the dictionary keys too (artists names); edit your question to make this point clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension with the replace method to update all the values (names of art pieces in this case) of the dictionary.

```py
art_dictionary = {
    "Wassily Kandinsky": "Composition VIII",
    "Zhou Fang": "Ladies Wearing Flowers in Their Hair",
 }
 
art_dictionary = {key:value.replace(' ', '_') for key,value in art_dictionary.items()}

print(art_dictionary)

# Output: {'Wassily Kandinsky': 'Composition_VIII', 'Zhou Fang': 'Ladies_Wearing_Flowers_in_Their_Hair'}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to replace " " with "_" in the keys too.

Comment: In the 2nd point mentioned in the question, the input required by the OP is the name of the art piece (painting_name = "Composition_VIII"), which is the value in the dictionary. There is no mention of updating the keys.

Comment: You're right, I assumed. Better ask OP for precisions.